# Redis serialization prefixed with extra string

Tags: redis, apache-camel

Camel-Redis's serializer is prefixing extra characters to message key.

When I checked the DB, the message key shows something like..

```
"\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x11test150827171118"
```

As you can see, the string `"\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x11"`

is prefixed for key `"test150827171118"`.

I tried two patterns,

Firstly, I set the serializer in the registry directly.

```
Registry.put("serializer", new StringRedisSerializer());
```

Second pattern is by setting in the RedisTemplate first. Then putting the redis template in the registry.

```
RedisTemplate<?, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
registry.put("redisTemplate", template);
```

Both cannot solve the problem of serizlization. Am I missing additional configuration for camel-redis.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the answer after five or six hours of googling and implementing on my development machine.

Camel `serializer` URI options is only for `CONSUMER`.
To affect `PRODUCER`, I also need to configure a custom `RedisTemplate` with `StringRedisSerializer` as default serializer.

```
redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
```

Then put both the serializer and redis template instance in registry and reference it from Camel URI.

```
registry.put("customTemplate", template);
registry.put("stringSerializer", new StringRedisSerializer());
```

Camel URI is like...

```
redis://<host>:<port>?redisTemplate=#customTemplate&serializer=#stringSerializer
```

Comment: Hi Yelo, Do you have a working camel redis project? Not sure how to configure RedisTemplate, getting error something related to PropertySet.